# To find value of $a^{\log b-\log c } b^{\log c-\log a } c^{\log a -\log b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

To find value of

$$a^{\log b -\log c } b^{\log c -\log a} c^{\log a -\log b }$$ where $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers. Now using formulas

i write this as $(\frac{b}{c})^{\log a }(\frac{c}{a})^{\log b }(\frac{a}{b})^{\log c }$

How do i proceed further from here?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoter explain your hatred !

Comment: Try using $x^{\log y} = y^{\log x}$ after applying $x^{y - z} = x^y / x^z$

Comment: This is what i have done

Comment: If you do it to the correct terms, they will cancel out.  You will have equal terms in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your formula is $a^{\ln b-\ln c} b^{\ln c-\ln a} c^{\ln a-\ln b}$. Let $x=$ this number, take $\ln$ on the both of sides, we get $\ln x=(\ln b-\ln c)\ln a+(\ln c-\ln a)\ln b+(\ln a-\ln b)\ln c=0$, then $x=1$.

Comment: How to do this without taking log on both sides

Comment: use $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$